# escape_javascript not properly escaping text_area's

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, formtastic

For some reason rails is not properly escaping text_areas for javascript. I am getting line breaks around text areas which leads to invalid javascript. I am using HAML and formtastic, but I thought the escape_javascript method handled the output after HAML was done with it. This is really frustrating. Please help...

example:

**edit.js.erb:**

```
$('#ajax-form').html("<%= escape_javascript render 'form' %>")
```

**_form.html.haml**

```
= semantic_form_for @note do |f|
  = f.input :body, as: :text
```

**Result:**

```
$('#ajax-form').html("<form id=\"edit_note\" action=\"/notes/123\" data-method=\"put\">\n<textarea name=\"note[body]\">
This is the note body </textarea>")
```

Notice the literal new line, this shouldnt be happening!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually a bug in Haml, upgrade to 3.1.6.rc.1 and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bug in Rails 3.2.3, it happened to me as well just after updating. Reverting to 3.2.2 solved it for now.

Comment: I rolled haml back one version and it fixed the issue.